# Change button's text with an external combobox java

Tags: java

I've two class. Can i change a text of a button in a class "home" with an actionlistener of the combobox in a class "panelGestisciImpianti"?  I don't unterstand becasue don't works.

The code is this:

//home

```
package s;
public class home extends JFrame {

private JPanel contentPane;
private panelImpostazioni panel5= new panelImpostazioni();
private JButton btnImpostazioni = new JButton("no"); //$NON-NLS-1$

public static void main(String[] args) {
    home frame = new home();
    frame.setVisible(true);

}


public home() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setExtendedState( JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH) ;

    setBounds(0, 0, 1963, 688);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

    btnImpostazioni.setBounds(0, 560, 140, 140);
    contentPane.add(btnImpostazioni);
    btnImpostazioni.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            contentPane.add(panel5);            
            revalidate();
            repaint();
        }
    });
}


public void changetext() {
    btnImpostazioni.setText("yes");
}   
}
```

//panelGestisciImpostazioni

```
package s;

public class panelImpostazioni extends JPanel {
    private JComboBox comboboxLingua = new JComboBox();
    static home h=new home();

    public panelImpostazioni() {
        setBounds(140, 0, 800, 560);
        setLayout(null);

        comboboxLingua.setBounds(100, 24, 150, 45);
        comboboxLingua.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] {"italiano", "inglese"}));
        add(comboboxLingua);
        comboboxLingua.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                h.changetext();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because when you create panel5 you have a new home created.
static home h = new home ().

So when you call changetext method you do it in a new invisible frame.

In order to make this work (it is really really bad) you have to pass your visible "home" as an argument to your panel5. Which means you have to initiate it in home's constructor and not as a field.

public panelImpostazioni(home h)

And in your combobox action listener
h.changetext ()

Comment: Sorry for being unable to write more. It is really difficult from phone :)

Comment: No problem, thank you :) Which can be a better method ?

Comment: I often like to use a singletonholder for the main frame and whenever i need the instance of the frame (which rarely i do) i get it from the singleton.

Comment: When you have ten minutes and you are with computer, can you give me an example? Thank you man. The reason for this question is that i would translate all text about my program in other languages.

Comment: Just google 'singleton java' and you will find it out.